# Set that only needs equals

Tags: java

I'm curious, is there any `Set` that only requires `.equals()` to determine the uniqueness?

When looking at `Set` classes from `java.util`, I can only find `HashSet` which needs `.hashCode()` and `TreeSet` (or generally `SortedSet`) which requires `Comparator`. I cannot find any class that use only `.equals()`.

Does it make sense that if I have `.equals()` method, it is sufficient to use it to determine object uniqueness? Thus have a `Set` implementation that only need to use `.equals()`? Or did I miss something here that `.equals()` are not sufficient to determine object uniqueness in `Set` implementation?

Note that I am aware of Java practice that if we override `.equals()`, we should override `.hashCode()` as well to maintain contract defined in `Object`.

Comment: The last note actually raise another question why `.hashCode()` is defined in `Object`. Is it because all objects in Java will somehow ends-up is a hash-based data structure? but this is answered in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113752/why-equals-and-hashcode-were-defined-in-object) and also perhaps in [Jon Skeet blog](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/12/05/redesigning-system-object-java-lang-object/)

Comment: It's worth noting that java.util.HashSet is backed by a java.util.HashMap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On its own, the `equals` method is perfectly sufficient to implement a set correctly, but not to implement it *efficiently*.

The point of a hash code or a comparator is that they provide ways to arrange objects in some **ordered structure** (a hash table or a tree) which allows for fast finding of objects. If you have only the `equals` method for comparing pairs of objects, you can't arrange the objects in any meaningful or clever order; you have only a loose jumble of objects.

For example, with only the `equals` method, ensuring that objects in a set are unique  requires comparing *each* added object to *every other object* in the jumble. Adding *n* objects requires
`n * (n - 1) / 2` comparisons. For 5 objects that's 10 comparisons, which is fine, but for 1,000 objects that's 499,500 comparisons. It scales terribly.

Because it would not give scalable performance, no such set implementation is in the standard library.

---

If you don't care about hash table performance, this is a minimal implementation of the `hashCode` method which works for any class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 0; // or any other constant
}
```

Although it is required that equal objects have equal hash codes, it is never required *for correctness* that inequal objects have inequal hash codes, so returning a constant is legal. If you put these objects in a `HashSet` or use them as `HashMap` keys, they will end up in a jumble in a single hash table bucket. Performance will be bad, but it will work correctly.

---

Also, for what it's worth, a minimal working `Set` implementation which only ever uses the `equals` method would be:

```
public class ArraySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
    private final ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (!list.contains(e)) {
            list.add(e);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

The set stores objects in an `ArrayList`, and uses `list.contains` to call `equals` on objects. Inherited methods from `AbstractSet` and `AbstractCollection` provide the bulk of the functionality of the `Set` interface; for example its `remove` method gets implemented via the list iterator's `remove` method. Each operation to add or remove an object or test an object's membership does a comparison against every object in the set, so it scales terribly, but works correctly.

Is this useful? Maybe, in certain special cases. For sets that are known to be very tiny, the performance might be fine, and if you have millions of these sets, this could save memory compared to a `HashSet`.

In general, though, it is better to write meaningful hash code methods and comparators, so you can have sets and maps that scale efficiently.

Comment: yes, I'm aware that O(n) in such critical data structure is not acceptable. I can imagine the `Set` will be part of a loop which can put the performance to O(n^2). But OTOH, I wonder whether some correctness mistake can be prevented by providing such implementation. See my comment to Ekleog answer.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer I've added an example of how to implement such a set.

Comment: Thank you. Although I'm not looking for workaround, just a rationale on why there is no such implementation in the standard API. Because I think, such data structure might prevent errors on programmer part that doesn't override hashCode when they override equals. I'll accept your answer because you answered my question that 1) I don't miss anything that `.equals()` is sufficient to build a `Set` data structure and 2) possible reason why there is no such implementation in standard API : performance. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* override `hashCode()` when you override `equals()`. The contract for `Object` clearly specifies that two equal objects have identical hash codes, and a surprising number of data structures and algorithms depend on this behavior. It's not difficult to add a `hashCode()`, and if you skip it now, you'll eventually get hard-to-diagnose bugs when your objects start getting put in hash-based structures.

Answer (score 2):

It **would** mathematically make sense to have a set that requires nothing but `.equals()`.

But such an implementation would be so slow (linear time for every operation) that it has been decided that you can always give a hint.

Anyway, if there is really no way you can write a `hashCode()`, just make it always return 0 and you will have a structure that is as slow as the one you hoped for!

Comment: Indeed. I am aware of the O(n) performance. But OTOH, our inherited codebase seems to suffer from identity problem whereby many classes override `.equals()` and not `.hashCode()`, and worse, these classes are used in hash-based data structure.

Thus I'm wondering whether the former programmer line of thought is something like, "I need Set data structure. TreeSet will need to implements Comparator. Nah, just use HashSet". Also, whether these kind of error can be prevented by having the `.equals()`-only-implementation of `Set`. It will cost O(n), but correct instead of O(1) but incorrect.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer why not fix your codebase straight away? Why some awkward workaround that is only going to lead to more trouble in the end?

Comment: Especially given that writing a `hashCode` function is really easy so long as you do not seek for optimal performance, and examples on the internet can help you write efficient ones.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: Yep, I already raised this to my senior dev and we are trying to get necessary resources, mainly time from the stakeholder because there are hundreds of them. And no, I don't ask the question because I'm looking for workaround, I'm just curious on rationale why this errors can be so pervasive. Design of Object that force on equality and hash code might be one reason (ref)[http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/12/05/redesigning-system-object-java-lang-object/] and, I think, lack of the `.equals()` only in `Set` might also contribute. Thus the question why it's not there.

Comment: @Ekleog, Indeed, we are planning to use Eclipse's equals and hashCode generator to expedite our effort.